# Error with return value

Tags: c++

So I am creating a random number generator and I keep getting a problem. In my program I have it print out the code into the "int main()" function. The problem is that it prints a 0 after. It's also saying I have to use return, but I don't want to. I want to keep the random number generator in another function because I will be adding much more in the future.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int randRoll();

//Calls the other function
int main()
{
    cout << randRoll() << endl;

    system("Pause");
}

//Gets the random number
int randRoll()
{
    srand(time(0));

    for (int x = 1; x <= 1; x ++)
    {
        cout <<"Your random number is " << 1 +(rand()%4) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eeeeeekkk!!.....Think about it in terms of responsibilities. The method (function) that return random numbers should do only that. The printing should be someone else's responsibility

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int randRoll();

// entry point
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));     // initialize randomizer

    cout << randRoll() << endl;

    system("Pause");

    return 0;
}

//Gets the random number
int randRoll()
{
    auto x = 1 +(rand()%4);

    // do something with x here (but don't call cout!)

    return static_cast<int>(x);
}
```

The problem you have is that you are not returning the randomly generated value (which I called `x` in my code). Also, you were trying to print out the randomly generated value twice (but incorrectly).

Comment: It's highly doubtful that the OP wants the return value from `srand`.

Comment: "main" will complain about not returning anything.

Comment: @Abhineet: no, `main` has a default return value.

Comment: I added a return value because I agree with @Abhineet, it's not pretty  to not return anything.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf `main` has default return value? I don't think so, but maybe I am wrong, so can you provide a reference link?

Comment: @hyde: The C++ standard isn't available for hyperlinking, and it costs quite a bit, but you can get a free draft from the committee pages (or even build it yourself). Then in C++98 through C++11 it's §3.6.1/5. (Sorry, I corrected that which was correct, sort of cross-eyed.)

Comment: I googled that up and the first link google threw is :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

using namespace std;

//Gets the random number
int randRoll()
{
    return 1 +(rand()%4);
}

//Calls the other function
int main()
{
    srand( static_cast<unsigned>( time(0) ) );

    for (int x = 1; x <= 7; x ++)
    {
        cout <<"Your random number is " << randRoll() << endl;
    }
}
```

---

Salient points:

- Preferably use e.g. `<stdlib.h>`, not `<cstdlib>`, to avoid some problems.
- Preferably avoid forward declarations of functions (also avoids some problems).
- Call `srand` only once.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << randRoll() << endl;
```

That prints out return value of that function, which is 0. How could not, when you tell it to print it? Well, like this, by not asking it to print return value:

```
randRoll(); // prints some random numbers
cout << endl; // prints newline
```

Then return value is ignored, and you can change it to `void` type if you want.

Note that as a whole, doing it like this might not make sense, but I think that answers your question and allows you to move on to next problem...

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course it prints two numbers, you asked it to!

```
// This prints "Your random number is [1-4]\n"
cout <<"Your random number is " << 1 +(rand()%4) << endl;

// This prints "0\n" since "randRoll()" returns 0
cout << randRoll() << endl;
```

Your main function could just be `int main() { randRoll(); }` because `randRoll` already prints something.